# Custom tag - get access to data in model?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jstl

I am creating a custom JSP tag by extending SimpleTagSupport.  Normally in the view, I could do something like `<c:out value="${key.attr}" />` using jstl to pull data from the model.  My question is: when creating custom tags (by using SimpleTagSupport), how do I gain access to the data from the model?  Thanks.

Just to clarify, I need a custom tag to do some formatting on a piece of data in the model.  I am open to suggestions if a custom tag is not the best approach for this (but would still love an answer to my original question).

**Update**: based on Bozhos answers it appears that I can grab the data from the model by using the JSP context.  Is this the typical way it is usually done (i.e. when a custom tag is used to manipulate a peice of data in the model before display)?  Or is it okay to pass the data as a parameter to the custom tag logic (i.e. via the tag attributes)?  I'm just trying to figure out the pros and cons of each method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All the data that JSTL manipulates is stored in the jsp context attributes. So you can get, for example, the `key` variable, by calling:

```
getJspContext().getAttribute("key");
```

There are four scopes for these attributes - page, request, session and application, so be careful where they are set. There is an overloaded method to provide a specific scope.

Of course, you can define a tag attribute instead and pass it that way.

Comment: so is this a better way of doing it than passing the data to the custom tag via a parameter?

Comment: now, that's a different story. You can, of course, pass it as parameter. But you can access other values from the page context as well.